# array/list management questionon c#, total noob

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

i am a total noob when it comes to c#
i migrated to a new platform which uses c#, trying to migrate trading rules to new design.
i need to do this for algorithm

here is the question 
i have keys array a,b,c,d
i have value set1 3,8,9,10
another value set2 77,89,100,76

these values are related to each other ,  (a) has values 3,77 and so on

what i need is , i need to filter with value set 2 , for example only values more than 80 then (probably create a new list with the remaining rows) , from the remaining list  i need to get the keyname  with highest set1 value

i tried it with this probably very bad way,

Array.Sort on one dimensional array value set1, take value[3] 
- if this equals 3 then (if value set1 >80 valuefound else take value[2] and repeat

can you show me an easier way , please take my inexperience into account and  include as more informatioan and code as possible

Comment: Use classes and manage them with specific  collection types like Dictionary or List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing what you want would be to use a `Dictionary` which holds keys and values together instead of having them in different arrays.

```
Dictionary<string, int[]> dic = new Dictionary<string, int[]>()
{
    { "a", new[] { 3, 77 } },
    { "b", new[] { 8, 89 } },
    { "c", new[] { 9, 100 } },
    { "d", new[] { 10, 76 } }
};
```

Then using LINQ you can retrieve the key really easily

```
string key = dic.Where(x => x.Value[1] > 80) // Filter by second value
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value[0]) // Order by first value
                .First() // Get the max value
                .Key; // Get the matching key
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really start learning more about Linq. C# has very powerful functional-like features that you can do these things really easily with. It's actually really fun :)

Basically, this code does what you want with 3 lines.

```
 var set1 = new[] {3, 8, 9, 10};
        var set2 = new[] {77, 89, 100, 76};

        var maxFromSet1 = set1
            .Zip(set2, (fromSet1, fromSet2) => new {FromSet1 = fromSet1, FromSet2 = fromSet2}) //Match the sets to one another
            .Where(zipped => zipped.FromSet2 > 80) // Filter by value
            .Max(zipped => zipped.FromSet1); //Gets max
```

Comment: i see this error 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Max<TSource,TResult>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: I ran the code and it works, have you made changes to it?

Comment: @peter  i copied the the full block.  But this isnıt visual studio . maybe i am missing some using statements , these exist   using System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable;
using System.Linq;

Comment: using System;
using System.Linq;

Also, I would recommend at least having Visual Studio installed (preferably with Resharper) for testing. intellisense can save you a lot of time.

Comment: i realised now System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable is wrong, But still says  "'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Max<TSource,TResult>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<T‌​Source>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context "

Comment: Okay my bad!!, error was caused by some line below , now it works . now i will try to do this with a table 30X5. hopefully it will be ok.  It may seem trivial noob question but if you saw my 250+ line code doing the same thing ,poorly , you would weep:)

Comment: Glad to be of service :)

Comment: is it possible to do this more than two arrays ?

Comment: Yes. You can run Linq on every IEnumerable (The C# interface for collections), and Zip returns an IEnumerable.

Comment: i meant in your example there are two arrays , i know the resulting max number but not the key it belongs to. is this because of some limitation? thanks for your help

Comment: No, I thought that's what you needed. 
In this case. I would replace Max() with the following:
.OrderBy(zipped=> zipped.FromSet1)
.Last().FromSet2